# Jquery for form with multiple save/submit buttons

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I have created a form using fields with two action buttons; one for the default submit functionality ('Save'), and the other one for custom submit functionality ('Submit').

When the user clicks the submit button a confirm box is displayed asking the user whether he wants to submit the form or not. If the user selects yes, the custom submit callback for the button should execute.

I am using the jquery-alerts plugin to display a customized confirm box on the click event of 'Submit' button. I used the following jquery code for this

```
$('#recommendation-letter-node-form #edit-save').click(function() {
  jConfirm("Once you submit the application, you will not be able to modify it any further. Are you sure you want to submit?", "Application Confirmation Dialog", function(confirm) {
    if (confirm) {
      $(this).submit();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

the `.submit()` function doesn't work for buttons other than default form submit button and I need that the other button submit callback should be triggered when the confirm value is true.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I used to achieved this was using the same callback function.  Then within this method, use $form_state['triggering_element']['#id'] or something similar to execute the proper function... i.e.

```
function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $id = $form_state['triggering_element']['#id'];

  switch ($id) {
    case 'edit-submit':
      submit_my_form($form, $form_state);
      break;
    case 'edit-save':
      save_my_form($form, $form_state);
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `$(this)` refered to first button(**save button not submit button** ), you should change 
`$(this).submit()` to `$('#yourformid').submit();`    .